# Pickadate.js does not open on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

after we've updated our pickadate from 3.5.4 to 3.5.6 the picker does not open on click. We are using the Date and the Time pickers, none of them shows up.

We're using different selectors like:

```
var options = {
    format: 'HH:i',
    editable: true,
    interval: 30,
};
$('.worktime').pickatime(options);
```

or

```
$('#datepicker').pickadate({
    labelMonthPrev: 'letzter Monat',
    labelMonthNext: 'nächster Monat',
    monthsFull: moment.months(),
    weekdaysFull: moment.weekdays(),
    weekdaysShort: moment.weekdaysShort(),
    // Buttons
    today: 'heute',
    clear: '',
    close: 'schließen',
    // Formats
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    formatSubmit: undefined,
    hiddenPrefix: undefined,
    hiddenSuffix: '_submit',
    hiddenName: undefined,
    // other
    firstDay: 1,
    selectYears: 4,
    editable: true,
});
```

Even if I run the code above in the console, it doesn't work. Only the following shows the picker:

```
var picker = $('#datepicker').pickadate('picker')
picker.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Version 3.5.4 the pickadate plugin is not binding any events when passing the "editable: true" parameter. We've had to bind the click and focus by ourselves in the new Version.

Answer (score 0):

If your only change was the update Pickadate.js from 3.5.4 to 3.5.6, then open a ticket at https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues and fall back on 3.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

event.stopPropagation() fixed it for me too